# Get elevated excel process

Tags: c#, excel, marshalling

A few days ago, I had to run Excel with current user rights using ProcessStartInfo in order to user some addins that require admin or current user rights.

```
 new Process{
     StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo{
          Verb = "runas",
          FileName = @"path/to/app.exe",
          Arguments = "-officeexcel",
          Domain = domain,
          UserName = login,
          Password = pa ss,
          UseShellExecute = false,
     }
 }.Start();
```

Thus, i can't use anymore :

```
Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
```

to get excel instance. So i tried to use late binding with AccessibleObjectFromWindow() :

```
int hwnd = (int)FindWindow("XLMAIN", null);

if (hwnd != 0)
{
      int hwndChild = 0;
      EnumChildCallback cb = new EnumChildCallback(EnumChildProc);
      EnumChildWindows(hwnd, cb, ref hwndChild);

      if (hwndChild != 0)
      {
          const uint OBJID_NATIVEOM = 0xFFFFFFF0;
          Guid IID_IDispatch = new Guid("{00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}");
          ExcelWindow ptr;

          int hr = AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hwndChild, OBJID_NATIVEOM, IID_IDispatch.ToByteArray(), out ptr);

          if (hr >= 0)
          {
              using (UILanguageHelper fix = new UILanguageHelper())
              {
                  return (Excel.Application)ptr.GetType().InvokeMember("Application", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, ptr, null);
              }
           }
      }
}

return null;
```

It worked but the Excel Application I get has zero property and I can't invoke any methods ! 
I need to run some macros after getting elevated Excel instance !

What did i do wrong ?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: why do you use reflection for this in first place?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot interact with an application launched in elevated mode from a non-elevated one for security reasons.

In your case, I think the only way to achieve what you ask is to elevate your app (or another small app dedicated to this task) first, then, your elevated app, will, on its turn, run excel and perform the tasks you require. Excel will run in elevated mode.

The design pattern in this way is to run your application with the minimum rights required. And then elevate, specifying in the command line a "token" (whatsoever you can use to connect to your application via IPC/sockets).